Firebase Remote Config need condition for QA testing (Web)
I want to create a condition in Firebase Remote Config for my QA team.
Previously, we used a country-based condition. For example, the condition was set for all users from Ukraine, and we received the necessary configuration.
However, now we need to implement it differently, and I’m thinking about using a condition based on user properties. Here’s an example of what I’m aiming for:
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const group = params.get('group');

if (group === 'qa' || process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_STAGE !== 'prod') {
    setUserProperties(firebaseAnalytics, {
        is_tester: '1',
    });
}

and after that we fetch and activete config
// ------------------ remote config ------------------
export const getValueByKey = async (key) => {
    await fetchAndActivate(remoteConfig);

    return getValue(remoteConfig, key)._value;
};

It works (we receive the needed value), but with a delay of 1-10 minutes and after a few page refreshes.
I need to implement a solution without the delay (in real time).
Any ideas ?
